# Unable to connect to a member server within a vpn network or vice versa, but why?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I've created a test VPC in AWS for an OpenVPN proof of concept.

In this VPC I've lunched a linux member server and an OpenVPN server AMI from AWS Marketplace, installed it and configured it.

As a client I am able to connect to the VPN network and to `ssh` into the OpenVPN server using each one of it's 3 ip's but the problem is that I'm unable to `ssh` into the member server in the VPC Main subnet.

Network is fully established between the OpenVPN server and the member server.

**The details are:**

```
VPC CIDR: 172.16.0.0/16
VPC Main Subnet CIDR: 172.16.200.0/24 
VPN CIDR: 172.16.201.0/24

OVPN server: 
Main Subnet interface: 172.16.200.66
VPN Server interface: 172.16.201.1
VPN Client interface: 172.16.201.129

Member server:
Main Subnet interface: 172.16.200.71

My Client IP: 172.16.201.131-134 (disconnected a few times)
```

**I've configured the OpenVPN server like so:**
[image]
**And:**
[image]

In addition, I've tried using NAT but to no avail.

When I run `tcpdump` from the OVPN server while trying to `ssh` from the client machine to the member server:

```
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ sudo tcpdump -i as0t1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on as0t1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
11:21:52.668974 IP 172.16.201.131.59009 > 172.16.200.71.ssh: Flags [SEW], seq 2266158529, win 65535, options [mss 1252,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 758529356 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
11:21:53.681875 IP 172.16.201.131.59009 > 172.16.200.71.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2266158529, win 65535, options [mss 1252,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 758530357 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

I can see that the OVPN server is trying to forward the packets to the member server but while running `tcpdump` on the interface of the member server I see that no packets arrive.

**Routes on the OVPN server:**

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.200.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.200.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.201.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 as0t0
172.16.201.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 as0t1
```

**Routes on the member server:**

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.200.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.200.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.201.0    172.16.200.66   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

**Routes on the client (my laptop), some of them have been manually added by me:**

```
netstat -nr | grep tun
172.16.200/24      172.16.201.134     UGSc            4        4   utun2
172.16.201/24      172.16.200.66      UGSc            1        2   utun2
172.16.201.134     172.16.201.134     UH              3        4   utun2
```

**Network interfaces on the OVPN server:**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:fb:99:4a:67:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.200.66/24 brd 172.16.200.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fb:99ff:fe4a:6704/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: pr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:ce:f1:ac:59:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::34ce:f1ff:feac:5942/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: as0t0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 200
    link/none
    inet 172.16.201.1/25 brd 172.16.201.127 scope global as0t0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: as0t1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 200
    link/none
    inet 172.16.201.129/25 brd 172.16.201.255 scope global as0t1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Network interface on the member server:**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:c5:62:3b:ef:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.200.71/24 brd 172.16.200.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c5:62ff:fe3b:ef02/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Some more points:**

`ping` from my client to the member server:

```
$ ping 172.16.200.71
PING 172.16.200.71 (172.16.200.71): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

`ping` from my client to the OVPN server (Using the VPC Main subnet):

```
$ ping 172.16.200.66
PING 172.16.200.66 (172.16.200.66): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.200.66: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=87.657 ms
```

`ping` from my client to the OVPN vpn ip's also works.

The routing table of this VPC in AWS:
[image]

These are my questions:

1. Shall I create a subnet of "172.16.201.0" (the vpn subnet) in the VPC? (I have, but it didn't solve the issue... it's just one of the things I've tried).
2. It seems like I'm missing something, maybe in the configuration in AWS, can you try and find my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 things you can have a look at

1. As it stands anything that is in the 172.16.0.0/16 CIDR range will be routed though the local route everything else 0.0.0.0/0 will be sent through the internet gateway. because your VPN subnet falls in to the 172.16.0.0/16 range this might be causing problems. may be:

a. choose a different address range for your VPN subnet

b. make sure there is a route in the route table that routes traffic to this subnet via the VPN device

1. Have you had a look at the security groups linked to your EC2 instances? do they allow the correct traffic (in this case SSH) that you want to flow to the those EC2 instance
2. Have you had a look at the Network ACLs that are linked to you VPC and its subnets, do they allow the correct traffic both inbound and outbound?

Comment: 1. I've started with CIDR 172.17.224.0/24 and when that didn't work I've changed to the current CIDR but that didn't solve the issue. 2. The attached SG is configured to allows SSH from both 172.16.0.0/16 and 0.0.0.0/0. 3. Checked.

Comment: How about the Security groups or Network ACLs?

Comment: Edited my comment

Comment: @ItaiGanot this absolutely **will not work** if you (a) use a subnet within the VPC supernet 172.16/16 for the VPN, or (b) add static routes to the instances -- *all* routing in VPC is done by the VPC route tables, or (c) don't remember to [disable the IP source/dest check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#change_source_dest_check) for the instance hosting the VPN.

Comment: Following your answer, I've deleted the VPN and started from fresh, now the VPC CIDR is identical to the subnet but the same problem persists, I have a feeling that it is related to iptables on the OVPN server